# Map reduce- Count of words starting with the letter a-z

Tags: mapreduce

I would like to get the count of number of words that start with letter "a-z" for which 'am trying this code but its just printing the count of number of words starting with "z".

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)

         throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     String line = value.toString();
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);

     while( itr.hasMoreTokens()){
         String token= itr.nextToken();

         if(token.startsWith("a-z")){
             word.set("A_Count");
             //word.set("Z_Count");
             context.write(word, ONE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post a line from the input file also. 
This code looks fine. Your logic is that there would be one single key called A_Count and in the reducer you will count the number of 1's in the list of values. Correct? And the Map emits A_count,1 whenever it meets a word that starts with the pattern a-z like a-zdfdgj, a-zererwui etc. But what makes you certain that it counts words starting with z alone?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this out and it runs fine.

```
 public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
            private final IntWritable VALUE = new IntWritable(1);
            private final Text KEY = new Text("COUNT");

            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                String line = value.toString();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    if(token.startsWith("a-z")){
                    context.write(KEY, VALUE);
                }
            }
         }
```

My reducer looks like

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, NullWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                int sum = 0;
                for (IntWritable val : values) {
                    sum += val.get();
                }
                context.write(new IntWritable(sum),NullWritable.get());
            }
    }
```